# CakePHP error handling misconfigured or could it be apache?

Tags: cakephp

I'm having a problem seeing some of my errors coming from CakePHP. I'm writing a component and after adding it in to $components of a controller I get a 500 error. Except that it's not helpful at all. All that is rendered is garbage. It looks like it's either zipped or an image. I'm seeing nothing but black diamonds with question marks, mixed with all sorts of characters.

Your help is appreciated. I'm running blind since I can't see what is wrong and don't know how to fix this.

Comment: When you say rendered, do you mean rendered to your log file? If so, delete the log file and recreate it with the proper utf-8 encoding or change the encoding with an IDE

Comment: No, this is what I see through the browser. It's a dev environment on my own computer. It's not going to a log.

Comment: First thing, check your cake log files : app/tmp/logs/
If you have nothing there, check your apache logs.
Then add the error log information along with your component code

Comment: Thanks, found the error log and that was more helpful. I'm still wondering why the browser output is garbage instead of displaying the error since debug is set to 2. The errors being output to the log are fine.

Comment: post some code. Typically black diamonds and `?` indicate a problem with character encoding, perhaps incorrect headers are being set. What are you processing - an image? Text?